# can't compile ruby 1.8.6 with zlib on smartos64

Tags: ruby, solaris, zlib, smartos

I'm trying install ruby 1.8.6 with zlib on smartos, the ruby compiles normal, but when I run ruby extraconf.rb that lives on ext/zlib folder the console shows:

```
[admin@7dabb5d6-09d4-42b3-bb40-36a7d0a0fabe ~/src/ruby-1.8.6/ext/zlib]$ ruby extconf.rb
checking for deflateReset() in -lz... no
checking for deflateReset() in -llibz... no
checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib... no
checking for deflateReset() in -lzdll... no

[admin@7dabb5d6-09d4-42b3-bb40-36a7d0a0fabe ~/src/ruby-1.8.6/ext/zlib]$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
[admin@7dabb5d6-09d4-42b3-bb40-36a7d0a0fabe ~/src/ruby-1.8.6/ext/zlib]$
```

how can I compile the zlib on smartos?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I solve my problem running:

```
ruby extconf.rb  --with-zlib-include=/usr/local/include/ --with-zlib-lib=/usr/local/lib
```

Thanks